# Update chekbox value using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox

I have the requirement where I'm using a checkbox, if the user has checked the checkbox then value of checkbox is saved as 1 and if it is left unchecked then value gets stored as 0.

This code works

```
//add 
<input type='hidden' name='status' value='0'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='status' value='1' <?php echo (isset($_POST['status']))?'checked':'';?>/>
```

When the data gets inserted in DB, checkbox will show checked if this value stored is 1. And when value is 0 it should show unchecked.

This also works

```
//edit
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="1"  <?php echo ($row['status'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>/>
```

Untill now its working.

But when user tries to edit this chekbox, the previous value gets stored in DB instead of the new one.

Comment: Well how about you show us some code, because with only this, help is minimal..

Comment: @Naruto i have already posted code , requirement is i m not able to update checkbox value

Comment: I don't see any relevant code of data being written to the database, which is your problem..

Comment: you have 2 `status` named field, what is always 0, because of the hidden